# Using Google Apps mail with my existing Gmail account

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I've been doing business using my current gmail address (company@googlemail.com) and really wanted my mail address to read info@example.com, so I looked into Google Apps.

It says you can set up custom emails with your domain name, achieving the above goal. How do I configure these addresses to run through my CURRENT Gmail account?

I have everything pretty well set up, and it would be very time consuming to effectively start again.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to be able to log in to your existing account, but be able to have emails to your company.com address show up there, and reply to those emails as if it's coming "from" your company.com address?

In that case, log in to your company.com account, go to Settings, and choose Forwarding/IMAP. Under Forwarding, choose Add a Forwarding Address and add your Gmail account.

Then, in your Gmail account, go to Settings, choose Accounts and Import, and under Send Mail As click "Add an email address you already own". Then enter your company.com email. Finally in the same section choose "Reply from the same address the message was sent to".

That said, if someone looks at the email header of mails sent this way, they will see it originated from your Gmail account and was sent "on behalf of" someone else. If that's not what you want, you'll have no choice but to switch over to the company.com account and use that "natively" instead. However in that case you can still import your old emails, filters, etc.